# Changing the avatar

Tags: discussion, user-profiles

I wanted to add an avatar to my profile here, but I don't feel like creating an account at this gravatar thing.

Is that the only option for setting an avatar image on here?

While trying to ask a question, I got the following error message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.

- Why am I getting this message?
- What can I do to get the system to accept my question?
- Can you be more specific?
- What are good resources on how to ask high-quality questions?

Answer (score 3):

1. There's no option for non gravatar icon profile: [Can we use non-gravatar avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4553)
2. Regarding the quality standard it generally means that your question is not well written and thus won't be easily answered: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074)

When you're faced to such broad question, have a look at [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), there's a good probability that your question has already been asked there.

Answer (score 1):

Now, it is possible to:

- Upload an image from your computer
- Use Gravatar
- Use Identicon

> [image: screenshot]